# send input value on click event

Tags: angular, angular5

i am trying to send the value of an input field, on "onClick" of a button event, what's wrong with that?

### html:

```
<input #new_field type="text" />
<button (click)="saveNewField(new_field.value)">Save</button>
```

### ts

```
saveNewField(new_name) {
// new_name is undefined
}
```

Comment: Code seems fine here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoq6rn-mrwgo9?file=src/app/keyup.components.ts

Answer (score 2):

You have to define value attribute to it, otherwise, it will be recognized as undefined.

```
<input #new_field type="text" value=""/>
```

Comment: No need to add `value` attribute I guess

Comment: check the example without `value` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoq6rn-mrwgo9?file=src/app/keyup.components.ts

Comment: i found the solution for my case, because the i am using`Primeng` the (click) should be (onClick).. + the input had a property `*ngIf=".." and the value was set to off, so it was `undefined`